# How a get a part of the string from main String in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have mainString from which i need to get the part of the string after finding a keyword.

NSString *mainString = "Hi how are you GET=dsjghdsghghdsjkghdjkhsg";

now I need to get the string after the keyword "GET=".

Waiting for a reply.

Comment: Why not take a look at the documentation for NSString, I think you'll find what you need there: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex via [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html):

```
NSString *mainString = @"Hi how are you GET=dsjghdsghghdsjkghdjkhsg";
NSString *matchedString = [mainString stringByMatching:@"GET=(.*)" capture:1L];
// matchedString == @"dsjghdsghghdsjkghdjkhsg";
```

The regex used, `GET=(.*)`, basically says "Look for `GET=`, and then grab everything after that".  The `()` specifies a capture group, which are useful for extracting just part of a match.  Capture groups begin at 1, with capture group 0 being "the entire match".  The part inside the capture group, `.*`, says "Match any character (the `.`) zero or more times (the `*`)".

If the string, in this case `mainString`, is not matched by the regex, then `matchedString` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Assuming your string really is so totally straightforward, you could do something like this:

```
NSArray *components = [mainString componentsSeparatedByString: @"GET="];
NSString *stringYouWant = [components objectAtIndex: 1];
```

Obviously, ***this performs absolutely no error checking and makes a number of assumptions*** about the actual contents of `mainString`, but it should get you started.

Note, also, that the code is somewhat defensive in that it assumes that you are looking for `GET=` and not separating on `=`.  Either way is a hack in terms of parsing, but... hey... hacks are sometimes the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But what if i dont get the keyword in the particular String ?.
It would crash then I guess

Comment: execute the second statement only after checking the count of the array 'components', it should be 2 or more for the index 1 to be there.get the count as
NSInteger count = [components count];
then using if statement if(count>1){NSString *stringYouWant = [components objectAtIndex: 1];}

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location of the first occurrence of `=` and then just take a substring of `mainString` from the location of `=` to the end of the string.